# Connecting Nexus to Confluent repository fails

Tags: maven, nexus, confluent-platform

being behind a Nexus Repository Manager (3.4.x) I'm trying to setup a connection to the Confluent repository / Maven. I tried several steps, the most complete instructions I tried can be found here: [Confluent Maven repository not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488853/confluent-maven-repository-not-working)

My workstation connects to a Nexus Repository Nexus. I have admin privileges on this Nexus.

[Remote repository settings -- Nexus (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwmH6.png)

[Further settings -- Nexus (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHjqi.png)

Using these settings I cannot connect to the Confluent repository. The Nexus works fine with other third party repositories.

I tried using the health check, but it just leaves me with 'Insufficient trend data' as shown here:
[Insufficient trend Data -- Nexus (3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTm8R.png)

I currently spend 1.5 days on this. I locally embedded some of the needed jars, but for production this is obviously not feasible.

What am I missing here? Is there a way to check availability of third party repositories from Nexus except Health Check? If you already have this setup running, I'm looking forward to your replies.

*Manually added:* 
kafka-avro-serializer, kafka-schema-registry-client 

Currently unresolable: common-config

Comment: I would check the remote repository http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ ? Which looks like not working ? Moved ...needing authorization etc. ?

Comment: It's the offical repository URL, reference: https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/installation.html#installation-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the URL you're pointing to packages.confluent.io/maven is returning a 404.

My guess is that this is causing Nexus to think that the downstream repository isn't working properly.

I'd contact the people who operate the confluent server and let them know the configuration in the documentation isn't working properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - It's the offical repository URL, reference: docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/installation.html#installation-maven. I read about the issue and it just seems to be a browser related issue and the repository therefore working fine

Comment: I was using CURL to inspect the repository and it was returning 404.  If you wanted to test further, you could see if an attempt to retrieve an actual artifact returned 200 rather than 404.

Comment: Please refer to the accepted answer of the linked article https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489639/6500730 'the root repo isn't browseable', which does not seem to impede Maven