# Having issues with using schema-registry:download

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am using the schema registry download maven from here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/maven-plugin.html, but I am not able to download the schema into my local project. Here is my plugin content.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <schemaRegistryUrls>
      <param>http://localhost:8081</param>
    </schemaRegistryUrls>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/avro</outputDirectory>
    <subjectPatterns>
      <param>MysqlTest2.oms.locations-value</param>
    </subjectPatterns>
    <subjects/>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can someone help with it? After I load the maven changes, should I click “clean” and “package” to make it work? Thank you so much!!

Comment: The plugin doesn't run on its own. What happens when you compile or package?

Comment: I click maven -- clean and package, but nothing new loaded into my project. I checked in both target and java folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you have the plugin repository

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository> 
        <id>confluent</id> 
        <name>Confluent</name> 
        <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url> 
    </pluginRepository> 
</pluginRepositories>
```

Then, the plugin has multiple goals, so you need to specify which to run, and wouldn't hurt to bind to the Maven phase before compile

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>avro-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>download</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
```

You should see output that looks like this in the Maven build

```
[INFO] --- kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:6.1.0:download (avro-resources) @ project ---
[INFO] Getting all subjects on schema registry...
[INFO] Schema Registry has XXX subject(s).
[INFO] Downloading latest metadata for mySubject-value.
[INFO] Writing schema for Subject(mySubject-value) to /project/src/main/avro/mySubject-value.avsc.
```

If you need to get a specific version, then see [Maven: downloading files from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741806/maven-downloading-files-from-url) and use the `/subjects/:name/versions/:number/schema` endpoint

Comment: Thank you, but I get this issue: The POM for io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:jar:6.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.164 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-12T16:28:45-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:6.0.1 or one of its dependencies

Comment: Plugin io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:6.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin:jar:6.0.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information ...

Comment: You didn't add the confluent maven repo https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907434/2308683

Comment: Could you please take a look at my answers below? I had that maven in my project, but I feel like there is some inconsistency in the pom file. Thank you again!

Comment: If the repo got added sucessfully, then you shouldn't see it trying to pull from `repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`. since it would be found in the other.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply again. It looks like my answer was not good and deleted by someone. I solved that issue by adding this ```  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>confluent</id>
      <name>Confluent</name>
      <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>``` Solved this issue following https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/630, but not sure why need to add this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, yes. Repositories block is only for dependencies, sorry forgot. But you need both, actually since you're using the Confluent serializer, and you don't need the maven plugins as dependencies, nor do you need the compiler and Avro plugins listed twice... Your "answer" was deleted because it was a response to my answer, not an answer to your question, so you should have edited the question instead

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from attaching the download goal to a maven phase which @OneCricketeer correctly mentions, you can also directly call the download goal of the plugin like the below one:

```
mvn schema-registry:download
```